# Can I legally drill a hole of 4" diameter in concrete load bearing beam through core cutting method?

Tags: concrete, beam

Can I legally drill a hole of 4" diameter in concrete load bearing beam above window through core cutting method?

Comment: Probably not. That's likely a third of the beam's height or more. That said, it's a question for a local engineer.

Answer (score 1):

No. You shouldn't drill any hole in a structural member without a structural engineer's or manufacturer's (who probably has an engineer on staff) approval, and they will tell you where you can locate it.